# NullArgument Exception in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, exception, generic-collections

The following query can throw a NullArgumentException in some cases, since items inside the `m_SelectedPayabes` collection can be null. How does the query need to be modified so that it doesn't throw  a `NullArgumentException` when it encounters a null reference?

```
var myPayables = from payable in m_Payables
where !(from o in m_SelectedPayabes select o.PBLE.PAYABLEID).Contains(payable.PBLE.PAYABLEID)                                     
select payable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either exclude the nulls:

```
var myPayables = from payable in m_Payables
                 where !(from o in m_SelectedPayabes 
                         where o != null
                         select o.PBLE.PAYABLEID).Contains(payable.PBLE.PAYABLEID)                                     
                 select payable;
```

Or replace the nulls with something else (assuming `o.PBLE.PAYABLEID` is an integer):

```
var myPayables = from payable in m_Payables
                 where !(from o in m_SelectedPayabes 
                         select o == null ? 0 : o.PBLE.PAYABLEID).Contains(payable.PBLE.PAYABLEID)                                     
                 select payable;
```

Comment: For every serial downvoter, a serial upvoter is needed. Here I come to the rescue!

Comment: I didn't vote, but the question says "sometimes `m_SelectedPayabe` is null" but you seem to be addressing instances where items inside `m_SelectedPayabes` are null. That may explain the vote. However, reading through the question it isn't exactly clear and seems everyone else is getting downvoted too...

Comment: @DanielKelley In that case, Konrad's answer is correct but still got downvoted.

Comment: Konrad's might be downvoted because the question specifically says he can't add an `if` statement first...

Comment: @Rawling the question said that he doesn't want to check wether the list has items or not. Which is different from checking if the list is null. Remember, 0 != null.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Thanks for pointing that out ಠ_ಠ Just giving a possible reason.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. The first solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following code before your query:

```
if (m_SelectedPayabes == null)
  m_SelectedPayabes = new List<...>();
```

or surrounf whole query with the proper condition like:

```
if (m_SelectedPayabes != null)
{
    // your query
}
```

Comment: correct answer. Don't know why you are being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It will check if `m_SelectedPayabes.PBLE.PAYABLEID` that matches `m_Payables.PBLE.PAYABLEID` and select `m_Payables` that do.

```
if (m_SelectedPayabes!= null && m_Payables!=null){
var x = m_Payables.Where(o => m_SelectedPayabes.Any(oo => oo.PBLE!=null && oo.PBLE.PAYABLEID == o.PBLE.PAYABLEID));
}
```

Comment: that'd still fail if m_selectedPayabes is null. See Konrad's answer.

Comment: `m_SelectedPayabes` is a table is it not? `m_SelectedPayabes.PBLE` might be null I suppose, I will add check.

Comment: could also be a List<>.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I suppose it can, I will wrap the statement in `if ` clause

Comment: m_SelectedPayabes is generic collection

Answer (score -1):

Just change your

```
from o in m_SelectedPayabes select o.PBLE.PAYABLEID
```

to

```
from o in m_SelectedPayabes.Where(sp=> sp!=null) select o.PBLE.PAYABLEID
```

Comment: that'd still fail if m_selectedPayabes is null. See Konrad's answer.

Comment: I get it, I just didn't think that someone could ask that kind of questions. I assumed it's all about items in the collection, my bad.